# How do I do 'from foo import *' using Python's __import__ function

Tags: python, import

I want to replace `settings.py` in my Django system with a module implemented as a directory `settings` containing `__init__.py`. This will try to import a module named after the server, thus allowing for per-server settings.

If I don't know the name of a module before I import it then I can't use the `import` keyword but must instead use the `__import__` function. But this does not add the contents of the module to the `settings` module. I need the equivalent of `from MACHINE_NAME import *`. Or I need a way to iterate over `vars(m)` (where `m` is the loaded module) and add them to the current namespace. But I can't work out how to refer to the current namespace in order to make the assignment. In other words, I can't use `setattr(x, ..)` or modify `x.__dict__`, because I don't know what to use for `x`.

I can't think of much else to try now apart from using `exec`. This seems a little feeble to me. Am I missing some aspect of Pythonic introspection that would allow me to manipulate the current scope while still in it?

Comment: Exact duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import

Comment: Thanks -- I did try to search for it, honest, but when the underscores are stripped off, __import__ is not a very specific search term... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For similar situation where based on lang setting I import different messages in messages.py module it is something like

```
# set values in current namespace
for name in vars(messages):
    v = getattr(messages, name)
    globals()[name] = v
```

Btw why do you want to create a package for settings.py? whatever you want to do can be done in settings.py directly?

Comment: The main thing is to keep the per-machine configuration files in their own directories so the don't clutter up the rest of the app. Since there is going to be a directory involved either way it seemed reasonable to put __init__.py there...

Comment: But the main point is that globals() is the current namespace -- it even says so in the documentation <http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals> -- but I always vaguely assumed it was the 'top' namespace, which is wrong.