# from ... import * with __import__ function

Tags: python, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`from . import x` using `__import__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408373/from-import-x-using-import)
>   [How does one do the equivalent of `import * from module` with Python's `__import__` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import)

How would I do the from ... import * with the `__import__` function?
The reason being that i only know the name of the file at runtime and it only has 1 class inside that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. **Just don't**. Do I need to explain just how horrible that it? Dynamically importing (though sometimes inevitable) and importing into global namespace (always avoidable, but sometimes the easier solution and fine withtrusted modules) are bad enough themselves. Dynamically importing into global namespace is... a nightmare (and avoidable).

Just do `_temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [name_of_class]); your_class = _temp.name_of_class`. According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#__import__), this is about what from name import name_of_class would do.

Comment: ya i got that too after looking at the docs. It didn't work at first, the reason for that is i forgot to declare the your_class as global. Thanks anyway

Comment: so in short, you say to use
`my_class = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [name_of_class]).name_of_class`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The answer below is much better.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone reading this wants an actual answer to the question in the title, you can do it by manipulating the `vars()` dictionary.  Yes, it is dumb to do this in most scenarios, but I can think of use cases where it would actually be really useful/cool (e.g. maybe you want a static module name, but want the contents of the module to come from somewhere else that's defined at runtime.  Similar to and, IMO, better than the behavior of `django.conf.settings` if you're familiar with it)

```
module_name = "foo"
for key, val in vars(__import__(module_name)).iteritems():
    if key.startswith('__') and key.endswith('__'):
        continue
    vars()[key] = val
```

This imports every non-system variable in the module foo.py into the current namespace.

Use sparingly :)