# from . import x using __import__?

Tags: python, import, module, python-3.x

How do I achieve `from . import x` (import module x from the current package), using `__import__`?

Here are some attempts that failed:

```
>>> __import__('.', fromlist=['x'])
ValueError: Empty module name

>>> __import__('.x')
ValueError: Empty module name
```

How is this done using `__import__`?

Answer (score 3):

The [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in's semantics are dovetailed with the bytecode that the interpreter generates from `import` statements, and are not especially convenient for manual use.  If I understand what you are going for correctly, this does what you want:

```
name = 'x'
mod = getattr(__import__('', fromlist=[name], level=1), name)
```

In versions of Python that have [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html), you *might* also be able to persuade `importlib.import_module` to do what you want with less ugliness, but I am not sure it is possible to get "`from .`" semantics that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
__import__(__name__, fromlist=['x'])
```

That should get you what you need.

Comment: This does an *absolute* import of `x`, which is not what was asked for; also, you need to do something with the return value.

Comment: @Zack: Yes, but since the absolute import uses the dynamically set name, you get the same result. But I'm not sure it works in a submodule.