# Imported module not recognised / defined

Tags: python, module, python-import

In my main module, I have the following:

```
function_dictionary = utilities.load_modules()
```

Which calls this:

```
def load_modules():

    function_dictionary = {}

    print "\nLoading modules..."
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("modules"):

        for name in files:

            if name.lower().endswith('.py') and name != "__init__.py":

                print "Importing " + os.path.join(path, name) + "..."

                try:
                    module = imp.load_source('utilities',os.path.join(path, name))
                    function_dictionary = dict(function_dictionary.items() + module.function_dictionary.items())

                except Exception, e:
                  print( "Import Error: %s" % str(e) )

    return function_dictionary
```

Now that the modules have been loaded, my main module calls this:

```
recovery.start("recovery.txt")
```

Which in turn calls this from the recovery module:

```
    if recovery:
        for command in content:
            print ("\n"+command)
            result = eval(command)

            if not result:
                continue_recovery = utilities.query_yes_no("Warning: Previous recovery command was failure, continue recovery?")
                if not continue_recovery:
                    break
    end()
```

I want eval to execute:

```
user_operations.remove_user(URL,acc_531,user_29080,"id",headers)
```

Where `user_operations` is the name of one of the imported modules and `remove_user` is a function within it.

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 7
6, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\pcli_front.py", line
 67, in <module>
    recovery.start_recovery(recovery_file, auto_recovery, headers)
  File "C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\recovery.py", line 1
21, in start_recovery
    result = eval(command)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'user_operations' is not defined
```

Is this because the imported modules are not within the scope of the recovery module? If so, does anybody know how to make it so they are?

Thanks

P.s I am aware Eval is evil etc etc

Comment: Why are you doing this?! What's wrong with regular `import`?

Comment: The modules are loaded dynamically so I have no idea what is and is not there.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312803/from-import-with-import-function) has the answer you're looking for (the second one). However, it looks like you have coded yourself into a corner (or someone else has), and this is probably not the *right* solution to get out of it.