# Python module import by module string name

Tags: python, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one do the equivalent of “import * from module” with Python's **import** function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import)

I'm trying to dynamically load a python module into the current module using a string for the name of the module.  The command I'm trying to emulate is

```
from modulename import *
```

except using a string variable instead of "modulename".  I'm having trouble understanding the python docs on import, but I see that if I do

```
_temp = __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

this is functionally equivalent to

```
import modulename as _temp
```

which is close to what I want.  But I want everything loaded into the current module's namespace.  I'm hoping there's another way to call `__import__` to accomplish this?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import