# Import variables from a user specified file in python

Tags: python, import, arguments

I want to import variables from a file that is specified as an argument. How do I achieve that?

For example: Say my file is myfile.py
I call it as

```
python myfile.py service.py
```

Now I want to import the variables of service.py in my myfile.py.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

inside of `myfile.py` insert an `__import__`

```
module = __import__(sys.argv[1].replace('.py', ''))
```

will import the first command line argument as `module` which you can then use as any other module that was imported.  The return value from `__import__` is a module.

Really in python, `import mod` is just a shorthand for `mod = __import__('mod')`, and you are allowed to call the `__import__` function if you do so choose.

An example:

```
>>> module = __import__("math")  #same as "import math as module"
>>> module.sqrt(16)
4.0
```

If you wish to pollute your global namespace with the contents of the command line argument, you can read about how to do a `from *` import here:
[How does one do the equivalent of "import * from module" with Python's __import__ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import)

Comment: You can then access variables such as `foo` specified in that module as `module.foo`, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

There are two questions that you could be asking.  The could be how do I import files to process on from the command line?  You can get the strings like this

```
fileName = sys.argv(1)
fileHandle = open(fileName, 'r')
```

If you want to find arguments in that file, It is a little bit harder.  I would need to know more about the format to help you.

Comment: I think you mean `sys.argv[0]` with brackets.  regardless, this isn't what OP is trying to do.

Comment: and actually, I think you meant `sys.argv[1]` because `0` will be the name of the program you're running