# Python- Importing a variable from a file name containing numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to import variables from `2WattTues` and `2WattWed` to `2WattThur` but I get this error, what can I do?

[image]

Comment: JFYI: Using `import * ` isn't a good practice

Comment: python scripts mustn't start with a number.

Comment: But in case you really have to, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9090079/770830) out.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example: *DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). This helps others more easily read and test your code.*

Comment: @Anthony - was I able to answer your question correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing like this

`wattTues = __import__('2WattTues')`

For performing import * check this out - 
[How does one do the equivalent of "import * from module" with Python's __import__ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147507/how-does-one-do-the-equivalent-of-import-from-module-with-pythons-import)

Answer (score 0):

Names of variables, modules (etc.) cannot start with a digit.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *identifiers* cannot start with a digit. It's a syntactic issue, not a limitation of the data model.